# How to configure tests stage in the codepipeline to use BatchBuild from Codebuild and create multiple instances

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am using CDK based code pipeline from https://github.com/awslabs/aws-simple-cicd . I would like to enable batchbuild in the test stage as per https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/aws-codebuild#Using-the-Cypress-Dashboard-with-AWS-CodeBuild

How can batchbuild be enabled in CDK codepipeline to have tests run in parallel?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I see `BatchBuild` can be enabled in the `CodeBuildAction`:

```js
const testAction = new CodeBuildAction ({
      actionName: 'Test',
      outputs: [testOutputArtifact],
      input: buildOutputArtifact,
      project: testProject,
      executeBatchBuild: true
    })
```

The docs states:

```js
    /**
     * Trigger a batch build.
     *
     * Enabling this will enable batch builds on the CodeBuild project.
     *
     * @default false
     */
    readonly executeBatchBuild?: boolean;
```

If You have any commands to run then it is possible to create `pre/post`-StageSteps.

I would also recommend You to use the simple [aws-cdk-lib.pipelines module](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines-readme.html) instead of [aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline module](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline-readme.html).

Comment: Thanks @ExceptionNotThrownException How do I extend this to specify the workers as mentioned here https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/aws-codebuild#Parallelizing-the-build ?

Comment: As far as I see the definitions are made as ```buildspec.yml``` files. You can read how to build a pipeline from these files here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines-readme.html#migrating-from-buildspecyml-files

Comment: Thanks. I gave it  ago , It continues to fail with It continues to fail with:

DOWNLOAD_BATCHSPEC

Client error

Logs say:


CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR=/codebuild/output/src420800698/src

[Container] 2022/09/19 23:37:46 YAML location is /codebuild/readonly/buildspec.yml

[Container] 2022/09/19 23:37:49 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: FAILED

[Container] 2022/09/19 23:37:49 Phase context status code: YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: yaml: unmarshal errors:

line 2: cannot unmarshal !!str `0.2` into float64

Comment: I tried going through the docs and added buildSpec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromObject({
        version: '0.2',
        batch: {
          'fast-fail': false,
          'build-list': [
            {
              'identifier': 'build_1'
            },
            {
              'identifier': 'build_2'
            }
          ]
        },

Comment: Look here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codebuild.BuildSpec.html#class-buildspec
You have multiple static methods for creating the BuildSpec Object.
Does Your solution work now?

Comment: @systemdebt I think batch builds do not have a version field, this is why you got that error. look at docs for build spec for batch build: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/batch-build-buildspec.html#build-spec.batch.build-list